# Pgcrypto doesn't work correctly on Windows

Tags: aes, postgresql-9.3, pgcrypto

I execute the same query on 2 different servers and I get a different results. Does anyone know why?

```
select decrypt('\x792135887dace2af15d3f8548cc20919','\x265bb788ef6762abf50577f8a6669aa0','aes-ecb')
```

Debian postgresql 9.3 server output (result expected):

```
"\xafb8967640bd0400309e7b0008acbb23"
```

Windows postgresql 9.3 server output (result wrong):

```
"\257\270\226v@\275\004\0000\236{\000\010\254\273#"
```

Comment: I tried on another database of the debian server with the same collation and I get the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Windows 9.3 server has a non-default configuration; it has `bytea_output` set to `escape` mode, not `hex` mode.

The result is actually the same, it's just being displayed in a different text representation of the underlying binary.

```
regress=> SHOW bytea_output;
 bytea_output 
--------------
 hex
(1 row)

regress=> SELECT BYTEA '\257\270\226v@\275\004\0000\236{\000\010\254\273#';
               bytea                
------------------------------------
 \xafb8967640bd0400309e7b0008acbb23
(1 row)
```